# How to convert dict with object as value to dataframe?

Tags: python

I have a Dict with object as value and  I want to create from it a DF 
(ignore the Nans)

```
list_of_actors[key] = value

key -> string

value -> Actor()
```

```
class Actor:
  def __init__(self,title,link):
    self.link = link
    self.title = title
    self.count = 1
    self.yearOfBirth ="NaN"
    self.countryOfBirth ="NaN" 
    self.numberOfAwards = "0"
```

```
columns = ['Name', 'Year of birth', 'Country of birth', 'Awards']
```

```
Name = self.title

Year of birth = self.yearOfBirth 

Country of birth = self.countryOfBirth

Awards = self.numberOfAwards
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it is not 100 % clear what you want. But I assume you want to convert a list of `Actor` instances into a dataframe.

We could add a `to_dict()` method on `Actor`, where we serialise the Actor into the dictionary, and turn a list of such dictionaries into a dataframe by simply using `pandas.DataFrame()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import typing as tp


class Actor:
    def __init__(
        self,
        title: tp.Optional[str] = None,
        link: tp.Optional[str] = None,
        count: int = 1,
        year_of_birth: tp.Optional[int] = None,
        country_of_birth: tp.Optional[str] = None,
        number_of_awards: int = 0
    ):
        self.link = link
        self.title = title
        self.count = count
        self.yearOfBirth = year_of_birth
        self.countryOfBirth = country_of_birth
        self.numberOfAwards = number_of_awards

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "Name": self.title,
            "Year of Birth": self.yearOfBirth,
            "Country of Birth": self.countryOfBirth,
            "Awards": self.numberOfAwards,
        }

actors = [Actor() for i in range(10)]  # Just to create a list of 10 
                                       # actors, put your actual actors 
                                       # list here 

actor_dicts = [actor.to_dict() for actor in actors]

df = pd.DataFrame(actor_dicts)
```

```
>>> df

   Name Year of Birth Country of Birth  Awards
0  None          None             None       0
1  None          None             None       0
2  None          None             None       0
3  None          None             None       0
4  None          None             None       0
5  None          None             None       0
6  None          None             None       0
7  None          None             None       0
8  None          None             None       0
9  None          None             None       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data frame using pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd

dict = {'Age': ['13', '13'], Country['Belgium', 'Italy']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

The keys of the dictionary will be the column names and the values will be the rows. So you will get:

```
   Age  Country
0  13   Belgium
1  13   Italy
```

Answer (score 0):

Before try the code below, you should only add the fields in the columns list, for this specific example they are: name, year, country and awards. 
Then, you can try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_actors[key for key in your_key_list], columns=columns)
```